# Circular dependency error in SCSS file in Rails 3.1 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sass

I've got **application.css.scss** in my assets/stylesheets directory, along with a number of controller-specific scss files.

The application.css.scss file has

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

And I have some ordinary scss following these directives.
When both require statements are enabled, I get *"/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss has already been required."* (There is no *application.css*, I've double-checked.)

Commenting out the ***require_tree .*** line eliminates the error, but obviously doesn't include the other scss files in the directory. The workaround is to require these files individually but that's not the long term solution. (Taking out the require_self line doesn't eliminate the error, either.)

I had thought Rails was smart enough to resolve this -- I have a feeling I've missed something obvious. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You say `it doesn't include the other scss files`. What are the other scss/css files and did you inserted the `*= require_tree .` in at least one of them? This would load the application.css file again. I had the same problem. I just removed these lines from all other css/scss files.

Comment: I also have carts.scss, line_items.css.scss, line_items.css.scss, products.css.scss, scaffolds.css.scss, and store.css.scss. None of them have require statements, only application.css.scss has them. Is there a debug mode that will force Rails to reveal what its compiled manifest looks like? (I have tried <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :debug => true %> to no avail)

Comment: As long as you are in development mode and assuming you did not modified the corresponding environment file the option `config.assets.debug = true` should be set. So `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :debug => true %>` will have no effect.