# Rails: How do I properly avoid a circular dependency error with my CSS but still include all the files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circular-dependency, sprockets

I am new to Rails, and I'm hoping this is a simple question, but I haven't been able to find it here or by Googling around. I've been through [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462661/sprocketscirculardependencyerror-in-storeindex) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803226/asset-pipeline-not-precompiling-sass) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327610/require-bootstrap-gets-sprocketscirculardependencyerror?lq=1) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702687/circular-dependency-error-in-scss-file-in-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline) but never fully fixed my issue. (The fourth link there, on "posts", is exactly the same problem, but it was never solved or answered.)

I'm trying to set up a *very* simple blog application for playing with. All I want to do (for now) is establish a global application.css[.scss is optional] and a page specific post.css[.scss].

My application.css looks like this:

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree .

body {
    background-color: #CCF;
}
#main_content_div {
    width:90%; 
    padding:10px; 
    margin: 15px auto; 
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Pretty straightforward if you ask me.

My post.css.scss looks like this:

```
.postlist_row {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Nothing fancy.

But when I try to visit /posts, I wind up with:

```
Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Posts#index
```

The standard SO answer to this seems to be "Well, just remove that require_tree statement. You're using Rails 3 and Sprockets, so that already happens and you're doubly including the same file(s)."

This is probably true. And if I remove that require_tree, application.css works fine. However, and this is where my problem seems to differ from others, **it never includes post.css.scss**. None of the ruls in it are applied to the page, and it isn't shown in the source.

I don't know enough yet about the pipeline to know for sure what the problem is, whether it's because of the order of my statements or because one is css and the other is scss or something with my configuration... I just have no idea.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `//= require_tree .` then you will need to include controller specific assets yourself.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline

> For example, if you generate a ProjectsController, Rails will also add
>   a new file at `app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee` and another at
>   `app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss`. You should put any
>   JavaScript or CSS unique to a controller inside their respective asset
>   files, as these files can then be loaded just for these controllers
>   with lines such as `<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>`
>   or `<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>`.

Have you done so?

Alternately you might want to leave the `//= require_tree .` so that your app can serve a single stylesheet for all requests (which the browser can cache after the first page) and use selectors to restrict some styles to specific pages. For example you might add `params[:controller]` as a class to your page body in your application's layout template so that you can then scope styles to apply only to that controller's views:

```
body.posts {
  .postlist_row {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I leave `//= require_tree .` in I get a circular dependency error. If I remove it and add assets in manually, then either template is no longer generic, since I have controller-specific stuff in there, or, if I add all the style sheets I might need for every page, I am serving up way more than I need to be for every call, neither of which are good solutions.

Is there a way to leave `//= require_tree .` in there without causing the circular dependency?

Comment: With the default asset structure you shouldn't see that circular dependency but in your example above I also don't see a require which would introduce one. Double check your changes and see if there's a require not mentioned above that would introduce that dependency?

Unrelated: serving a large single compressed asset with all of your styles is not necessarily a bad idea since it really is only served once and cached for every subsequent request from that client. If you do want to serve per-controller assets that shouldn't make your templates "not generic".

Comment: I'm stumped with this. I definitely don't have any other requires. The only css files present are the two above (and those are the entire files) plus home.css.scss, which only has autogenerated comments (no requires), and scaffolds.css, which is also autogenerated and contains a bunch of default rails styles, but again, no requires. I'm thinking the project configuration was broken somewhere along the way. I may just start from scratch; I'm not very far in.